# Couldn't get ConfigSlurper in Gradle project

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle

Am working on a system built in Gradle 2.2 with groovy plugin 2.3.7 !
My problem is my IDEA ( Intellij 14 )  didn't recognise ConfigSlurper groovy class when i tried to define new object of this class.

Tried to recompile the groovy plugin with no result !

Any help or tips would be appreciated !

Edited :
I figured it out and it was groovy sdk version that wasn't configured!

Comment: what do you mean by "does not recognise"?  is your code building fine, but intellij is showing errors or is the class at all not available and also build fails?

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file?

Comment: my code is building fine ! the thing is i want to use ConfigSlurper class and it seems like the class is not available ( intellij couldn't resolve it when i try to define an object with this class )

Comment: I've added build.gradle file in the main question !

Comment: have you refreshed your deps in intellij.  what kind of gradle integration are you using?  wrapper, ...?

Comment: i did ! yes am using gradle wrapper

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-gradle-projects.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html

Comment: Does it work when running gradle from the command line?

Comment: @Mich how did you solve this? I also got error cannot resolve `ConfigSlurper` but manage to build project

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you upgrade your gradle and IntelliJ doesn't seem to realize it.

Checking it out again from source control in a new directory and reopening it seemed to make it happier.